# How do I get the area of a triangle of 3 points in PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I want to compute the area of a triangle with 3 points with QGIS or PostgreSQL/PostGIS. The points are saved in a geometry column. I have no clue how to do it...

Answer (score 2):

Try [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html), e.g.

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT 
  'POLYGON((7.23 49.95,10.04 52.91,11.62 49.89,7.23 49.95))'::geometry AS poly) 
SELECT ST_Area(poly) FROM j;

      st_area      
-------------------
 6.581499999999988
(1 Zeile)
```

Using `geometry` parameters it ..

> Returns the area of a polygonal geometry. For geometry types a 2D
>   Cartesian (planar) area is computed, with units specified by the SRID

and using `geography`  ..

> For geography types by default area is determined on a spheroid with
>   units in square meters.

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT 
  'POLYGON((7.23 49.95,10.04 52.91,11.62 49.89,7.23 49.95))'::geography AS poly) 
SELECT ST_Area(poly) FROM j;

      st_area      
-------------------
 52245336562.55078
(1 Zeile)
```

**EDIT**: To create a polygon based on three points use ST_MakePolygon and ST_MakeLine (see comments):

```
WITH j (p1,p2,p3) AS ( 
  VALUES ('POINT(7.23 49.95)','POINT(10.04 52.91)','POINT(11.62 49.89)'))
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[p1, p2, p3, p1])),2)
FROM j;

                        st_astext                         
----------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((7.23 49.95,10.04 52.91,11.62 49.89,7.23 49.95))
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i know of st_area, the thing is i dont know how to get a polygon from the geometry column points. I thought of something like Select ST_AREA(ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_MAKELINE

Comment: @ArezZera I see. Can you post a sample of how your data is stored in the column?